# Find differences of 2 collections with 40K objects

Tags: c#, linq, plinq

I have 2 collections both containing the same type of object and both collections have approximately 40K objects each.

The code for the object each collection contains is basically like a dictionary except I've overridden the equals and hash functions:

```
public class MyClass: IEquatable<MyClass>
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        return obj is MyClass && this.Equals((MyClass)obj);
    }

    public bool Equals(MyClass ot)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(this, ot))
        {
            return true;
        }

        return 
         ot.ID.Equals(this.ID) &&
         string.Equals(ot.Name, this.Name, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase); 
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
         unchecked
         {
             int result = this.ID.GetHashCode();
             result = (result * 397) ^ this.Name.GetSafeHashCode();
             return result;
         }
    }
}
```

The code I'm using to compare the collections and get the differences is just a simple Linq query using PLinq.

```
ParallelQuery p1Coll = sourceColl.AsParallel();
ParallelQuery p2Coll = destColl.AsParallel();

List<object> diffs = p2Coll.Where(r => !p1Coll.Any(m => m.Equals(r))).ToList();
```

Does anybody know of a faster way of comparing this many objects? Currently it's taking about 40 seconds +/- 2 seconds on a quad core computer. Would doing some grouping based on the data and then comparing each group of data in parallel possibly be faster? If I group the data first based on Name I would end up with about 490 unique objects and if I grouped it by ID first I would end up with about 622 unique objects.

Comment: Before anything, consider caching the hash code. You lose some time by calculating it each time.

Comment: What is `Name.GetSafeHashCode()`? Perhaps caching your HashCode so it doesn't get recalculated might help, but I'm not sure by how much (you'll also have to invalidate/recalculate it if/when `ID` or `Name` change)

Comment: I think, you must avoid LINQ to achieve performance. If you can get your collections ordered, it will be best point.

Comment: @HamletHakobyan You don't need to order the collections for good performance; putting them in hash based sets would be better than ordering (which is what most of the LINQ set operations do).  You could use LINQ, but you don't *have* to.  Using a `HashSet` directly would be just as good, and only slightly more code.

Comment: @Chris The GetSafeHashCode is just a generic extension method that checks if the object is null first and then returns the objects GetHashCode() value or 0.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use [Except](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb300779.aspx) method which will give you every item from `p2Coll` that is not in `p1Coll`.

```
var diff = p2Coll.Except(p1Coll);
```

---

**UPDATE** (some performance testing):

Disclaimer:

Actual time depends upon multiple factors (such as content of collections, hardware, what's running on your machine, amount of hashcode collisions etc.) that's why we have complexity and Big O notation (see Daniel Brückner comment).

Here is some performance stats for 10 runs on my 4 years old machine:

```
Median time for Any(): 6973,97658ms
Median time for Except(): 9,23025ms
```

[Source code](https://gist.github.com/4486992) for my test is available on gist.

---

**UPDATE 2:**

If you want to have different items from both first and second collection you have to actually do [Expect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb300779.aspx) on both and that [Union](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341731.aspx) the result:

```
var diff = p2Coll.Except(p1Coll).Union(p1Coll.Except(p2Coll));
```

Comment: Really, it is faster? Are you tested?

Comment: This should be quite a bit faster - the solution from the question is `O(m * n)`, this solution internally builds a hash table and is therefore `O(m + n)`.

Comment: Not _excatly_ the same as the op's query since `Except` also removes any duplicates from `p2Coll`.

Answer (score 0):

[Intersect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb460136.aspx)

```
int[] id1 = { 44, 26, 92, 30, 71, 38 };
int[] id2 = { 39, 59, 83, 47, 26, 4, 30 };

IEnumerable<int> both = id1.Intersect(id2);

foreach (int id in both)
    Console.WriteLine(id);

/*
This code produces the following output:

26
30
*/
```

Comment: But `Intersect` does the opposite. He was looking for a way to get the differences.

Comment: But `Except` is not the difference either (unless the second set is guaranteed to be a subset of the first one). It is however what the code given in the question computes.